# Variable number of crawled items each run using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, settings

I am using Scrapy to crawl a website that contains a category menu with different sub-levels of categories (i.e. category, subcategory, sub-subcategory, sub-subcategory, etc (depending on each category)).

For example:

```
--Category 1
    Subcategory 11
        Subsubcategory 111
        Subsubcategory 112
    Subcategory 12
        Subsubcategory 121
            Subsubsubcategory 1211
            Subsubsubcategory 1212
--Category 2
      Subcategory 21

...
```

There are approximately 30.000 categories, subcategories, subsubcategories, etc and I am only scraping this section following one Rule:

```
rules = [
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=['//div[@class="treecategories"]//a',],
        ),
        follow=True,
        callback='parse_categories'
    )    
]
```

And it seems to work fine. The problem is that each time I run my scraper I get a different amount of crawled items and I know the website is not being updated. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

This is the settings I am using:

```
settings = {
    'BOT_NAME'                        : 'crawler',
    'USER_AGENT'                      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36',
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS'             : 64,
    'COOKIES_ENABLED'                 : False,
    'LOG_LEVEL'                       : 'DEBUG',
 }
```